# Merge sorted infinite streams

Tags: scala, stream

Given a finite number of sorted infinite streams. How to merge those stream into a single sorted infinite stream? e.g.

```
def merge[T](ss: List[Stream[T]]): Stream[T]
```

Comment: Please read the [asking guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for _homework help_ must include a summary of the **work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a description of the **difficulty you are having** solving it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
def merge[T: Ordering](ss: List[Stream[T]]): Stream[T] = {
    val str = ss.minBy(_.head)
    val (containsMin, rest) = ss.partition(_.head == str.head)
    containsMin.map(_.head).toStream #::: merge(containsMin.map(_.tail) ++ rest)
  }
```

This would take from smaller to bigger and it is assuming that the streams are ordered in that same way

Comment: Thank you, I derived a little bit your solution. But all the credits are your

def mergeSortedStreams[T](ss: List[Stream[T]])(implicit ord: T => Ordered[T]): Stream[T] = {
    val nss = ss.filter(_.nonEmpty)
    if (nss.isEmpty) Empty
    else {
      val min = nss.minBy(_.head)
      val oss = nss.filter(_ != min)
      min.head #:: mergeSortedStreams(min.tail +: oss)
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to create a method with this signature that support infinite streams. You'll run out of memory because all elements of original streams will be in scope during execution. 
Please read this article for explanations  http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/programming/scala/stream-hygiene-i-avoiding-memory-leaks/ .

Answer (score 0):

The sorted bit is probably not relevant as to be able to sort you need the stream to be strictly evaluated (then a Stream is not the type you want). But you can keep the "order" where the elements are evaluated.

I would probably try something like this:

```
scala> val s1 = Stream.from(1)
scala> val s2 = Stream.from(1000)

scala> val streams = List(s1, s2)

scala> val newStream: Stream[Int] = 
  streams.foldRight(Stream.empty[Int])(
                   (xs, xss) => xss #::: xs))
scala> newStream.headOption.foreach(println)
1
```